# hover changing id specific division

Tags: html, css

This is a solution-way question to another question I asked before ([Open 100% width Navigation on hover over navigation item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66081435/open-100-width-navigation-on-hover-over-navigation-item))
I am trying to build a navigation bar that shows more in depth search terms as soon as you hover over the respective navigation bar item.

Now I think I am close to a solution: I created this separate div that should be visible as soon as one hovers over "Produkte" / #navigation-item2. Now with the way I am acustomed to :hover this does not work. How can I make this work?

```css
.navigation {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 20vh;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  ;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.navigation-item {
  position: relative;
  height: 10%;
  width: 15%;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0.5em 1em 0.5em 1em;
  margin: 0px 1% 0px 1%;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: background 200ms linear;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navigation-item:hover {
  background: lightgrey;
}

.nav-menu {
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 25vh;
  opacity: 0;
}

#navigation-item2:hover #nav-menu2 {
  opacity: 1
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="navigation">
    <a href="https://www.amazon.com" style="flex: 0.5; margin-left: 20px">
      <img src="/images/Logo.png" alt="Logo" style="height:100%; width:auto; max-height: 16vh; margin-top: 3px;">
    </a>

    <a class="navigation-item" href="https://www.amazon.com">
          Home</a>



    <a class="navigation-item" href="https://www.amazon.com">
          Portfolio</a>



    <a class="navigation-item" id="navigation-item2" href="https://www.amazon.com">
            Produkte</a>



    <a class="navigation-item" href="https://www.amazon.com">
            Über uns</a>

  </nav>

  <div class="nav-menu" id="#nav-menu2">
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="https://www.amazon.com">Kochmesser</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www.amazon.com">Küchenmesser</a></li>
        </ul>
        <li><a href="https://www.amazon.com">Scheren</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.amazon.com">Klingen</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: You cannot access like this in CSS. Check out the: [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

Answer (score 0):

What `#navigation-item2:hover #nav-menu2` means, is that it targets the child element #nav-menu2 when the parent #navigation-item2 is hovered.

What you need to do is to move the `#nav-menu2` inside the nav-tag, because you can only target siblings (with `+` or `~`) or child elements.

I moved `#nav-menu2` so it's directly follows the relevant `a` tag. Then you can use `#navigation-item2:hover + #nav-menu2` to increase the opacity to 1.

By positioning every single sub-menu in the same order in the DOM, you can even go a step further, which I show-case in the code below, using only the classes.

For the sake of demonstration, I changed the `#nav-menu2` to a starting opacity of 0.1. I also positioned `#nav-menu2` to align at the bottom of `.navigation` (hence, adding `position: relative` to `.navigation`), and then translated it's full height (100%) to have the #nav-menu2 position itself under the navbar.

---

I would even go one step further and place `#nav-menu2` inside `#navigation-item2`, so you automatically get the correct x-position. It would also solve the issue that you look the hover state if you got outside the `.navigation-item`. But I leave that up to you to figure out.

```css
.navigation {
  position: relative;  /* ADDED */
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 20vh;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  ;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.navigation-item {
  height: 10%;
  width: 15%;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0.5em 1em 0.5em 1em;
  margin: 0px 1% 0px 1%;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: background 200ms linear;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navigation-item:hover {
  background: lightgrey;
}

.nav-menu {
  height: 200px;
  bottom: 0px;                  /* ADDED */
  transform: translateY(100%);  /* ADDED */
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 25vh;
  opacity: 0.1;                 /* CHANGED */
}

.navigation-item:hover + .nav-menu { /* CHANGED */
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="navigation">
    <a href="https://www.amazon.com" style="flex: 0.5; margin-left: 20px">
      <img src="/images/Logo.png" alt="Logo" style="height:100%; width:auto; max-height: 16vh; margin-top: 3px;">
    </a>

    <a class="navigation-item" href="https://www.amazon.com">
          Home</a>

    <a class="navigation-item" href="https://www.amazon.com">
          Portfolio</a>

    <a class="navigation-item" id="navigation-item2" href="https://www.amazon.com">
            Produkte</a>

    <div class="nav-menu" id="nav-menu2">
      <ul class="dropdown">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="https://www.amazon.com">Kochmesser</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.amazon.com">Küchenmesser</a></li>
          </ul>
          <li><a href="https://www.amazon.com">Scheren</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www.amazon.com">Klingen</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    
    <a class="navigation-item" href="https://www.amazon.com">
            Über uns</a>
  </nav>


</header>
```